# Implement a notification type server in Java

Tags: java, android, notifications

I keep searching but only find examples with servers doing broadcast. I would like to have a simple example tutorial with:

- Client
- Server
- MessageToSend (**serializable object**)

The server should manage the **connections**, and receive a `MessageToSend` from `client_one` to `cliente_two;` while `cliente_three` communicates with `client_four` in a independent way.

Polling could be a solution, but i would really prefer to implement notification "**style**".
I have searched for polling and notification types but i cant find much.

Later on this should be implemented with android, but for now, i would like to implement normal java app.

Thanks!

Comment: If your goal is to send notifications to Android devices, you are probably going the wrong way. I recommend you learn about push notifications, the Google Cloud Messenging Service: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/index.html

Comment: Android SDK manager shows that Google Cloud Messaging is deprecated. Can i use it anyway? What can be my limitations using it?

Comment: Hmm really ? They say Android Cloud to Device Messaging (C2DM) is deprecated and GCM replaces C2DM.

Comment: in my Android SDK manager i have: [Deprecated] Google Cloud Messaging for Android Library. Im trying now to download it.

Comment: Seems http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gcm/package-summary.html is deprecated indeed, but replaced by http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i would like to implement this client/server using android, i have found a goode tutorial online where they show how to use Google Cloud Messaging (GCM) to create an instant messaging app like WhatsApp or Facebook Messenger.

http://www.appsrox.com/android/tutorials/instachat/#4